Delete old logs not working with log4j2 xml configuration
I have log4j2 xml configuration. Issue is that- log older than 1 day is not getting deleted. Log files are in same application root folder. Can anyone please help what is the issue
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="allLogsFile" fileName="${sys:log_name}"  filePattern="${sys:log_name}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{DATE} %-10X{session} %-8X{user} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
<Policies>
<OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2000KB" />
</Policies>
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5">
<Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
<IfFileName glob="*" />
<IfLastModified age="P1D" />
</Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Logger name="com.test.*" additivity="false" level="debug">
<AppenderRef ref="allLogsFile" />
</Logger>
<Root level="debug">
<AppenderRef ref="allLogsFile" />
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>

Thanks

From you description it isn't clear if ${sys:log_name} is contained in ${baseDir}. Can you give the expanded value of these placeholders? The * glob matches files in the ${baseDir} folder, but not in subfolders. Use ** if you want to match the content of subfolders.

${sys:log_name} is contained in baseDir. I am setting log file name dynamically.              Also, log file is in application base folder:  <application_folder>/*.log                                          And my log4j2 xml is in application subfolder:   <application_folder>properties/log4j2.xml
